# Как исключить данные из БД при выборе?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Имеется БД. Из нее в php документе я выбираю записи. 
Подскажите каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при выборе какой-либо записи, происходила проверка, на то, что данная запись еще не выводилась. 
Лучше всего, чтобы если одно значение уже было выбрано, то данная запись просто исключалась  из списка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При выводе заносишь значение во временной массив, при каждом последующем выводе проверяешь отсутствие выводимой записи в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Если данные быстро обновляются, то есть один вариант как то сортировал по времени, то есть показывал X записей и записывал в ссылке (или переменной js) на следущую страницу в виде времени последней записи, а новые динамически добавлялись на страницу относительной первой записи, далее GET запрос со значением page.php?time=время-последней-записи

Если данные не слишком быстро обновляются, то можно изначально делать запрос в БД используя LIMIT 0, 30 например.

Так же есть более сложный вариант, передавая в запросе например через запятую id показанных записей page.php?none=123,324,657,353, если много значений, то POST, ну а далее в php обрабатывать это. Все зависит от того для чего это надо.

Answer (score 0):

Так может нужен просто список неповторяющихся  (уникальных) записей, которые можно перебирать без удаления дублей впоследствии?

Тогда поможет [Distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp), выполняемый на уровне sql-запроса к базе.